# cp: cannot stat : No such file or directory

Tags: package-management, python, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to copy the python package from the source directory in `.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` to another folder. Following is the command that I'm using

```
cp -R home/my_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/ home/my_name
```

This gives me following error

```
cp: cannot stat 'home/my_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/': No such file or directory
```

The directory and its content exist, as I have checked it.

How should I carry out the copying task?

Comment: I guess you should have a '/' in front?  i.e., `cp -R /home/my_name/...`?

Comment: Oh?  Ok...  I was thinking there might have been something else, after you added it in.  I'll write it up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the command that you have written, you need a forward slash (`/`) in front of the source and destination paths.  So, change your command to:

```
cp -R /home/my_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/ /home/my_name
```

This is because you are referring to both the source and destination from the root (`/`) directory.  Without, the command would still work, but *only* if you current working directory happened to be the root directory.  i.e., this would work, too:

```
cd /
cp -R home/my_name/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/ home/my_name
```

And unrelated to your question, but if it's your own directory, you can replace `/home/my_name/` with `~`.  i.e.,

```
cp -R ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/ ~
```