# Script stopped working - No such file or directory

Tags: bash, ubuntu-mate

This script used to work before, but now it does not work at all.

I checked log and this is the error I got

```
andy@7 ~/Downloads> grep 'emptytrash60.sh' /var/log/syslog > home/andy/Downloads/emptytrash.txt
bash: home/andy/Downloads/emptytrash.txt: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: See [cp: cannot stat : No such file or directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1338834/cp-cannot-stat-no-such-file-or-directory) and [When to use a preceding slash in path names? (e.g. for the 'cd' command)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607413/when-to-use-a-preceding-slash-in-path-names-e-g-for-the-cd-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a slash at your home path.
Change `home/andy/Downloads/emptytrash.txt` to `/home/andy/Downloads/emptytrash.txt`